# Group by in SQL Server and then rows merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the below query to Count some data

```
select Count(BrowserName) as Count,BrowserName from UserSession
group by BrowserName
```

The result I get is as below

```
Count BrowserName
3      IE
4      InternetExplorer
5      Chrome
6      Safari
```

I was just wondering how can I group the IE and InternetExplorer together so I get results in the below format

```
Count BrowserName
7      IE
5      Chrome
6      Safari
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
select (case when BrowserName in ('IE', 'InternetExplorer') then 'IE'
             else BrowserName
        end) as BrowswerName,
       Count(*) as Count
from UserSession
group by (case when BrowserName in ('IE', 'InternetExplorer') then 'IE'
               else BrowserName
          end);
```

If you have a lot of matches, then using `JOIN` might be simpler:

```
select coalesce(v.new_browsername, us.browsername) as browsername,
       count(*)
from UserSession us left join
     (values ('InternetExplorer', 'IE')
     ) v(browsername, new_browsername)
     on us.browsername = v.browsername
group by coalesce(v.new_browsername, us.browsername);
```

You can add matched pairs in the `values()` list for further substitutions.

Comment: Lol I was just thinking after posting that now Gordon will come and answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `REPLACE()`.

```
select 
    Count = Count(*)
    ,BrowserName = REPLACE(BrowserName, 'InternetExplorer', 'IE')
from UserSession
group by REPLACE(BrowserName, 'InternetExplorer', 'IE')
```